# Sendy (hosted with Hostinger) email campaigns time-out constantly

Tags: sendy

Even with the CRON job setup (below) my Sendy email campaigns time out after around 1,400 sends (about 10% of the list).

- - - - - /usr/bin/php /home/u202277730/domains/blastoff.us/public_html/sendy/scheduled.php

Hostinger customer-service have been dancing around the issue, and swear that they are not throttling the outbound SMTP send.   Can anyone help?

Rowan

Comment: Using any (or most) hosting to send emails is a bad idea. The ips are shared with many clients, the chances that your emails go to spam boxes are high. Alsl although they say that do not throttle, they probably do. Use AWS SES to send your emails... Is cheap (or free)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use SES to send out emails, that way mail merging with the api will be far faster and more powerful, and you don't have to put up with mail deliverability issues.

An AWS lightsale node starts at 3.50/mo but also allows you to use the SES free tier, (62k emails a month, about $6.20 worth).

Hope this helps and also saves you a few dollars here and there.

Matt